# Formspree contact form not working angular5

Tags: typescript, http, angular5, firebase-hosting, angular-forms

So I'm trying to integrate a [formspree](https://formspree.io/) contact form into my angular5 site and am running into some issues. It works fine when testing on localhost and emails come through as intented. But when I deploy my site to firebase hosting, the form is not working. Checking the console on the firebase site it looks like the form is going through without issue and the response is always `{success: "confirmation email sent"}` but no confirmation email is ever recieved.

Here's the code:

email.component.ts

```
export class EmailComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;
  success: boolean;
  emailPattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$';
  subjectPrefix: string;

  constructor(private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.submitted = false;
    this.success = false;
    this.subjectPrefix = 'WEBSITE CONTACT: ';

    this.route.queryParams
      .filter(params => params.success)
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);

        this.success = params.success;
        console.log(this.success);
      });
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]),
      subject: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      message: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    }, {
      updateOn: 'blur'
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.http
        .post('https://formspree.io/your@email.com', {
          name: this.form.value.name,
          _subject: `${this.subjectPrefix}${this.form.value.subject}`,
          email: this.form.value.email,
          message: this.form.value.message
        })
        .map(res => console.log(res.json()))
        .subscribe(
          success => console.log('success'),
          error => console.log('error')
        );
    }
  }
}
```

email.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <!-- NAME INPUT -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'error' : form.controls['name'].errors && (form.controls['name'].touched || submitted)}">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].errors && (form.controls['name'].touched || submitted)" class="text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].errors.required">Name is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- EMAIL INPUT -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'error' : form.controls['email'].errors && (form.controls['email'].touched || submitted)}">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Your email">
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors && (form.controls['email'].touched || submitted)" class="text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors.required">Email is required.</div>
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors.pattern">Please enter valid email address.</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- SUBJECT INPUT -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'error' : form.controls['subject'].errors && (form.controls['subject'].touched || submitted)}">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="subject" name="_subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="form.controls['subject'].errors && (form.controls['subject'].touched || submitted)" class="text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['subject'].errors.required">Subject is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- MESSAGE INPUT -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'error' : form.controls['message'].errors && (form.controls['message'].touched || submitted)}">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" formControlName="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="form.controls['message'].errors && (form.controls['message'].touched || submitted)" class="text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['message'].errors.required">Message is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
    <span class="fas fa-paper-plane"></span>
    Send
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: The first time you send the email you get an email with a link to enable the form from your URL. Did you check if you got any emails like that to enable on your URL?

Comment: No that's the problem I think. It says that a confirmation email was sent but I don't actually get anything. I did check spam folder as well.